# How to disable AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

How can I disable AnkhSVN in VS 2010?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works more or less the same for all SCC Providers:

1. Go to File -> Subversion -> Change Source Control. Use this to disconnect the solution (this is to avoid auto-reloading AnkhSVN the next time you open the solution).
2. Go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control. Select None (or a different SCC Provider)

Comment: This seems to work until I close and then re-open the solution, and its set back to SVN again. I also tried running VS as admin (vs 2015 community).